# Show that $\tau= \{U \subseteq X: A \subseteq U \ \text{or} \ U = \emptyset\}$ is a topology on $X$ as follows.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Let $X$ be a set and $A$ be a finite subset of $X$. Define $\tau$ as follows:
$$\tau= \{U \subseteq X: A \subseteq U \ \text{or} \ U = \emptyset\}.$$

1. Show that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.
2. Show that any intersection of open sets is again open.

**Attempt:**

1. **First,** it's clear that $\emptyset,X \in \tau$.
   **Second,** let $U,V \in \tau$. We want to show that $U \cap V \in \tau$. To this end, if $U = \emptyset$ or $V=\emptyset$, then $U \cap V = \emptyset \in \tau$. So, assume that $U \ne \emptyset$ and $V \ne \emptyset$ with $U \cap V \ne \emptyset$.
   Since $U \in \tau$, then $A \subseteq U$. Similarly, since $V \in \tau$, then $A \subseteq V$.
   Hence, $A \subseteq U \cap V$. Thus, $U \cap V \in \tau$.
   **Third,** let $\mathcal\{U\} \subseteq \tau$. We want to show that $\cup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$.
   To this end, if $\mathcal{U} \in \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$, then $\cup \mathcal{U}=\emptyset \in \tau$. So, assume that $\mathcal{U} \not \in \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}$ with $\cup 
   \mathcal{U} \ne \emptyset$. Now, let $M \subseteq \cup \mathcal{U}$ be arbitrary. Then, there exists $U \in \mathcal{U}$ such that $M \subseteq U$. Since $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \tau$, $M \subseteq U$ and $U \in \mathcal{U}$, then $M \in \tau$. Since $M$ was arbitrary, then $\cup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$.

Therefore, we conclude that $\tau$ is a topology on $X$.

2. I think, to show this, it suffices to show for infinite intersection, since the finite was proved above. Isn't it?

Does this correct? Thanks in advanced.

Comment: "any intersection" and "finite intersection" do not mean the same thing. However, the fact that 2.) hold should be clear from the definition of $\tau$

Comment: @user1090793 So, what does "any intersection" means? And, what about the proof of 1., especially the third axioms?

Comment: For the third: Let $\mathcal{U} \subseteq \tau$. We want to show that $\cup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$. Notice that
$$\cup \mathcal{U}= \bigcup_{U \in \mathcal{U}} U.$$
For any $U \in \mathcal{U}$, we have $A \subseteq U$. Then so the union is, i.e.,
$A \subseteq \cup \mathcal{U}$. Hence, $\cup \mathcal{U} \in \tau$.

What about this approach? Which one is correct between this and the above attempt?

Comment: This one is not correct because it pretends $\cal U$ has some element $\ne\varnothing$ and has no element $=\varnothing$. Your above '"attempt" is *entirely* correct.

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks for the feedback, Sir.